# 2d density plot in orthographic projection in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I get artifacts when plotting 2d density estimates in an orthographic projection. The problem is that the contour lines don't wrap around at the date line. Can this be done in ggplot2?

```
library(tidyverse)

# points on a map, longitude between -180 and 180
df = data_frame(lon=c(rnorm(100, -180, 50), 
                      rnorm(100, 180, 50)), 
                lat=rnorm(200, 60, 10)) %>% 
     filter(lon > -180, lon < 180)

# 2d density, orthographic projection
ggplot(data=df) +     
  coord_map('ortho') + 
  geom_point(aes(x=lon, y=lat)) + 
  stat_density2d(aes(x=lon, y=lat))
```

[image: ggplot2 artifact in 2d density plot with orthographic projection]

Answer (score 2):

Not sure that it is exactly what you are looking for :

```
m <- mapproject(df$lon, df$lat, projection="orthographic", parameters=NULL, 
orientation=NULL)


ggplot(data=as.data.frame(cbind(m$x, m$y))) +     
  geom_point(aes(x=V1, y=V2)) + 
  geom_density2d(aes(x=V1, y=V2))
```

Comment: Maybe. I notice that the points on your `ggplot(data.frame(m$x,m$y))` are in different positions from my `ggplot(df)`. Could it be that the default orientation of `mapproject` is different from the northpole-centering of `coord_map('ortho')`?
 Thanks!

Comment: Would the calculation of the density be correct with this method? Shouldn't it be computed before the reprojection?

Comment: That's another valid concern. It's true that the density estimate will depend greatly on the shape of the kernel used, which in turn depends greatly on the projection.